# how to load data in uitableview without reloading every time

Tags: ios, uitableview, afnetworking

I have a collection view in my app. I load images to collection view cells using AFNetworking. When user taps on a collection view cell, another view appears with a table view. In my case when user navigates to  the table view for the first time it takes much time to load data. Then user comes back to the collection view and tap thes same cell, table view appears, but data loads again from the beginning.
What I want to: when user goes to the table view first time data should load, and when users goes to the same table view again, previous loaded data should be there. Can I do that using cache or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach depends on how your dataSources are implemented.

You can store your tableView dataSource where your collection view data lays, so after first fetch it would be saved and you init your tableView with existing dataSource.